# Why does TSQL Table Partion seem to stop working?

Tags: t-sql, datatable, partitioning

For a number of reasons, but mostly the sheer volume of data, we have 5 MS-SQL (2017)sharrded servers to break up the overall load on any individual server.  Secondly we have a real-time table that is partioned by asset ID in order to store the real-time data.  Data packets arrive approximately every 2 seconds for each asset.  Each data packet can have from 300 to 12000 datapoints.

The table partioning and sharded servers work very well.  But every once in a while it seems that one of the servers seems to stop using the portioning which results in deadlocks and timeouts as new data arrives.

My question is why is this occurring, and is there a way to check to see when or why this is happening.  I know that this is the issue since I can move the data to a staging table, drop the original table, recreate the original table with the same partion function and scheme and copy data back from the staging table to the new "original" table and the issue is resolved.  The only thing I can think of is the SQL Profiler might some how mess with the portioning function/shcema